# Error while integration with android and unity hardware does not support this application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I integrate android with unity.
I am not able to run unity class
I got this error,

```
Failed to initialize! Your hardware does not support this application, sorry!
```

I have issue with following line..

```
protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); 
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        setContentView(mUnityPlayer);


    }
```

I have an error on line setContentView ..

How can I solve this problem?
please help me to solve this..
There is no realm file in the project

Comment: What device are you using? And what version of Unity?

Comment: Unity 5.3.. Android version 5.1

Comment: Android device:one plus two..I also checked with other device but same problem...